# How to put two or more Elements sit next to each other with overflow?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slide

I would like to know how to put two or more Elements sit next to each other with overflow. I can do it if I change the width of the slide-screen for example 1500px or bigger. I need to hide the second image to make a slide with javascript later. Please teach me how to solve this problem or teach me another way to do it if there is...

HTML

```
    <div class='slide-screen'>
  <div class='image' id='one'></div>
  <div class='image' id='two'></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.slide-screen{
  border:2px solid red;
  height:500px;
  width:700px;
  overflow-x:scroll;
}

.image{
  display:inline-block;
}

#one{
  float:left;
  height:500px;
  width:700px;
 background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1621361950750-21eba89575de?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwxNDU4OXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHx8MTYyMjk0MzY0OA&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85');
  background-size:cover;
}

#two{
  float:right;
  height:500px;
  width:700px;
 background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1621361950750-21eba89575de?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwxNDU4OXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHx8MTYyMjk0MzY0OA&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85');
  background-size:cover;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make a container for the images and set the width to the total amount of both pictures (plus a little bit more), then set it to display inline-block. Now you have 2 images side by side.  Then you're outer container you can set with the overflow to scroll. See here:

```css
.slide-screen{
  border:2px solid red;
  height:500px;
  width:700px;
  overflow-x:scroll;
}

.container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1410px;
}
.image{
  display:inline-block;
}

#one{
  height:500px;
  width:700px;
 background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1621361950750-21eba89575de?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwxNDU4OXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHx8MTYyMjk0MzY0OA&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85');
  background-size:cover;
}

#two{
  height:500px;
  width:700px;
 background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1621361950750-21eba89575de?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwxNDU4OXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHx8MTYyMjk0MzY0OA&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85');
  background-size:cover;

}
```

```html
<div class='slide-screen'>
  <div class="container">
    <div class='image' id='one'></div>
    <div class='image' id='two'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `max-width` css property, which will hide the image once it reaches a certain width.